# Extract Characters Before And After Middle Symbol regex and rest string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a file name like this

```
1x5 Girl In The Flower Dress.mkv
```

It means `Season 1 Episode 5` of  `In The Flower Dress`

```
2x6.English,.Fitz.or.Percy.avi
```

It means `Season 2 Episode 6` of  `English, Fitz or Percy`

How to extract Season number ,Episode number and series name

Comment: This is a really simple regular expression. What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Use `\d` to match digits, `x` to match the middle symbol, and use capture groups to get the parts that match.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and let you know @Barmar

Comment: Is it is like `if (preg_match("/\dx\d/",'1x5 Girl In The Flower Dress.mkv', $n)) ` @Barmar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capture groups to get the parts of the string that match parts of the pattern.

```
preg_match('/(\d+)x(\d+)\s*(.*)/', '1x5 Girl In The Flower Dress.mkv', $match);
```

`$match[1]` will be `'1'`, `$match[2]` will be `'5'`, and `$match[3]` will be `'Girl in the Flower Dress.mov'`.

You need to use `\d+` to match more than one digit in the season or episode number.

Comment: Thanku for this . Can I use `str_replace($match['0']," ",$srt);` to get series name

Comment: You could just add another capture group to get everything after it.

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
2x6.English,.Fitz.or.Percy.avi
```

Try this:

```
preg_match("/(\d*)x(\d*).?(.*)\.(.*)/", $input, $output_array);
```

output_array

```
array(
  0 =>  2x6.English,.Fitz.or.Percy.avi
  1 =>  2   // Season 
  2 =>  6   // Episode
  3 =>  English,.Fitz.or.Percy  // title
  4 =>  avi
 )
```

Comment: Thanku for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

How about a more direct solution?

```
$title = '2x6.English,.Fitz.or.Percy.avi';

preg_match_all('~(?:(\d+)x(\d+)|(?!^)\G)[^\w\r\n,-]*\K[\w,-]++(?!$)~m', $title, $matches);
$matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);

echo "Season {$matches[1][0]} Episode {$matches[2][0]} of ".implode(' ', $matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Season 2 Episode 6 of English, Fitz or Percy
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I wanted to write: `$out=preg_split('/[\. x]/',$in,3,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` but because the title words can be dot delimited AND you don't want to capture the file suffix, I had to bin that method.

Barmar's method includes the file suffix, so that will require additional handling.  Ravi's pattern isn't as refined as it could be.

Revo's method is inspired, but requires 4x as many steps as my pattern.  [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pzFx0n/1)  Both of our methods require an additional function call to prepare the title.  I find my method to be very direct and doesn't require any array filtering.

```
$input[]='1x5 Girl In The Flower Dress.mkv';
$input[]='2x6.English,.Fitz.or.Percy.avi';

foreach($input as $in){
    preg_match('/(\d+)x(\d+)[ \.](.+)\..+/',$in,$out);
    echo "<div>";
        echo "Season $out[1] Episode $out[2] of ",str_replace('.',' ',$out[3]);
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Output:

```
Season 1 Episode 5 of Girl In The Flower Dress
Season 2 Episode 6 of English, Fitz or Percy
```